# How to access views inside TableLayout

Tags: android, button, tablelayout

In `TableLayout` there are 9 `Buttons` in a 3x3 format. How to access the text on these buttons programatically using the id of TableLayout (not Button Id) ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use something like,

```
TableLayout tblLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
TableRow row = (TableRow)tblLayout.getChildAt(0); // Here get row id depending on number of row
Button button = (Button)row.getChildAt(XXX); // get child index on particular row
String buttonText = button.getText().toString();
```

**3x3 format:** (Code for understanding actual may be different)

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
 TableRow row = (TableRow)tblLayout.getChildAt(i);
  for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
    Button button = (Button)row.getChildAt(j); // get child index on particular row
    String buttonText = button.getText().toString();
    Log.i("Button index: "+(i+j), buttonText);
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me solution if the `TableRow` has a `LinearLayout` inside it and inside that `LinearLayout` i have my `Button` whose text i want to access. (NOTE: There are many `LinearLayout` inside one `TableRow` and none of the `Button` have `ids` as i have defined the layout for buttons in one layout file and included it as many times i need it)

Comment: @Ramswaroop - Just call recursive function which loop all child of `ViewGroup` and if you found child view as a `Button` stop the loop.

Comment: @user370305 hypothetically, if I had a table layout with 5 table rows without any buttons, can I do this:
`TableLayout tblLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);`
`TableRow row = (TableRow)tblLayout.getChildAt(0); // Here get row id depending on number of row`
`String Text = row.getText().toString();`

Answer (score 6):

What you can do is find the instance of `TableLayout` using

```
TableLayout layout_tbl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_tbl);
```

then by using `getChildCount()` you can iterate through each child of `TableLayout` and `TableRow`, also better to check `View` by using `instanceof` so that you don't get any `NPE`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < layout_tbl.getChildCount(); i++) {
     View parentRow = layout_tbl.getChildAt(i);
     if(parentRow instanceof TableRow){
                for (int j = 0; j < parentRow.getChildCount(); j++){
                   Button button = (Button ) parentRow.getChildAt(j);
                   if(button instanceof Button){
                      String text = button.getText().toString();
                }
       }
   }
```

Comment: In a loop you assigned Button button = ... And after that check: if (button instanceof Button). Please, correct an answer.