# How to display user's inputs on dialog?

Tags: java, android

I am having trouble with passing the user's input data into an alert dialog in Android.

I was given a class that will ask for an user's input and it will assign each input with an ID. Like so,

```
public void inputRow( TableLayout tl, String label, int inputSize, int inputID )
    {
        TableRow inputRow = new TableRow(this);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        EditText edit = new EditText(this);

        // some margin
        inputRow.setPadding( 20,10,20,0);
        tv.setText(label);
        edit.setMaxWidth( inputSize*7)  ;
        edit.setMinimumWidth(inputSize*7);
        edit.setId( inputID );
        edit.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        inputRow.addView(tv);
        inputRow.addView(edit);

        tl.addView(inputRow);
    }
```

Then the input rows will be something similar to this:

```
inputRow(myTableLayout, "Name", 30, 10000);
inputRow(myTableLayout, "Email", 20, 10001);
```

Then an alert dialog will be created to display a message when the button is clicked:

```
final AlertDialog alertDialog;
alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
alertDialog.setTitle("Your Inputs");
alertDialog.setMessage("Inputs");
```

But when I tried to load the `.setMessage()` with the assigned IDs, it will return null. I was given a hint to use the function View `.getID()` but I am still fairly new to java and having trouble using this function. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to pass what the user enters in the EditTexts or are you trying to show those EditTexts views in the dialog for the user to enter data on them?

Comment: @Luksprog Yeah, I am trying it to pass what the user enters in the EditText in the alert dialog. I should have included an example (my bad), after you enter your name and email, when the "Your Inputs" button is clicked, it should display a dialog display the name and email you have entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the ids of the `EditText`s you should be able to do it like this:

```
//if you do not have a reference to the EditText already -- this uses the IDs in your question
EditText nameEditText = (EditText) myTableLayout.findViewById(10000);
EditText emailEditText = (EditText) myTableLayout.findViewById(10001);
String nameValue = nameEditText.getText().toString();
String emailValue = emailEditText.getText.toString();

// now you can do whatever you need to with the values
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Your Inputs")
            .setMessage("Name is: " + nameValue + ", Email is: " + emailValue)
            .create();
dialog.show();
```

**Update with more code**

Below code works fine for me, using your `inputRow()` function:

```
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);

    inputRow(tableLayout, "Name", 30, 10000);
    inputRow(tableLayout, "Email", 20, 10001);

    Button doneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.done_btn);

    doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override public void onClick(View v) {
        //if you do not have a reference to the EditText already -- this uses the IDs in your question
        EditText nameEditText = (EditText) tableLayout.findViewById(10000);
        EditText emailEditText = (EditText) tableLayout.findViewById(10001);
        String nameValue = nameEditText.getText().toString();
        String emailValue = emailEditText.getText().toString();

        // now you can do whatever you need to with the values
        AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .setTitle("Your Inputs")
            .setMessage("Name is: " + nameValue + ", Email is: " + emailValue)
            .create();
        dialog.show();
      }
    });
  }
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

  <TableLayout
      android:id="@+id/table"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/done_btn"
      android:text="done"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Picture of output]

Comment: I have no problem running the code but when I click the button, it only outputs "Name is:" and "Email is:". What gives?

Comment: Is there anything entered into the name and email `EditText`s when you launch the dialog?

Comment: Yes. I tried multiple times with different characters are well.

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much Alex!

Answer (score 0):

You need a reference to each edit text you want to extra from for your dialog,

You could do this by:

- crawling through your TableLayout with getChildAt (see [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504718/how-to-access-views-inside-tablelayout)).

OR

- just saving each value in a separate list during the callback of a
     text changed listener on the EditText

Then, with that reference, you can get the value with getText().toString() - see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText()